# Elixir: Pattern match with multiple map match options

Tags: phoenix-framework, elixir

In Elixir instead of writing something like:

```
case getUser(id) do
  %User{status: "pending"} -> something()
  %User{status: "available"} -> something()
  _ -> something_else()
end
```

I simplified it into:

```
case getUser(id) do
  %User{status: "pending" | "available"} -> something()
  _ -> something_else()
end
```

But got an error:

```
cannot find or invoke local |/2 inside match. Only macros can be invoked in a match and they must be defined before their invocation. Called as: "pending" | "available"
```

is there a better way of doing this? I don't want to write the same function twice.

Comment: Please amend your code to use curly brackets for structs. What is posted would not even compile.

Comment: Thank you, I’ve edited - it was an error while typing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
case getUser(id) do
  %User{status: status} when status in ["pending", "available"] -> something()
  _ -> something_else()
end
```

The `when .. in` is a [Guard](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/guards.html) and is mentioned briefly on the [case, cond, and if](https://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/case-cond-and-if.html) page.

Comment: `status in ~w|pending available|` :)